# Unity bone gizmo disappeared

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I've been using Unity with the 2D Animation package for rigging my multi layered sprite. It worked like a charm, rigged the thing, created my animations but.. all the sudden the gizmo showing the bones in my editor disappeared :(

I fear it happened when updating Unity to 2019.2.12f1 but cannot guarantee

This is what I see:

[image]

The bones ARE there, I can move them and I can animate them, but I cannot see the gizmo for easy manipulation :(

In the past it did look like this:

[image]

Where one can drag and drop easily the bones and rotate them

This is how my layers look like in the editor:

[image]

The bones are in the Player layer

Any clue ??

Answer (score 0):

Simply select all the "bone" GameObjects, go to the Inspector and choose a gizmo from this menu

[image]

The ones in the first row additionally show the objects name in the SceneView:

[image]

---

If you already did that but they are still not showing up make sure

- you have the Gizmos enabled at all

  [image]
- The Gizmos size is big enough

  [image]

  If the size is too small the Gizmos are faded out if you are too far away!

---

If the "bones" use a specific component which defines the Gizmo you an also check in the `Scripts` and `Built-in Components` lists whether the according type's Gizmo was maybe disabled.

---

Some other tries:

- go to the Inspector of a bone and make sure the according component(s) is(are) not folded.
- make sure there are no hidden layers in your scene (top right in the editor)

  [image]

  Gizmos are not shown if the according layer is "hidden"

---

For further options see the [Gizmos Menu](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html)

Comment: nop. Does not work. I added and example on how it did look before the update in my question

Comment: Are these objects using a specific component or are they only transforms?

Comment: Ive no clue, but they look pretty custom. I also noticed that using the `Gizmos.DrawSphere(center,range);` that used to work.. is also no painting anything. But in the Gizmos section of the editor I have checked ALL ticks available :(

Comment: Can you check if you have maybe a layer disabled for the SceneView? (Top right `Layers` drop-down) And just for trying are all components on the bone objects unfolded in the Inspector?

Comment: I added an screenshot of how my "layers drop-down" looks like. I'd say everything is marked for rendering.. am I right ?